# Spring transaction management. NoRollbackFor not working

Tags: java, spring, jpa, transactions, spring-boot

I've got one SpringBoot enabled app with the following setup:

`@Configuration` class is annotated with `@EnableTransactionManagement`

TransactionManager is defined somewhere in the `@Configuration` class:

```
  @Bean
        public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
            return new JpaTransactionManager();
        }
```

@Controller class:

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.DELETE, value = "/{entityId}")
    @Transactional(noRollbackFor = DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<DeleteEntityResponse> deleteEntity(@PathVariable @NotNull long entityId) {
        T existing = getRepository().findOne(entityId);
        try {
            repository.delete(existing);
            repository.flush();
            deleteEntityResponse.setDeleted(true);
        } catch (final DataIntegrityViolationException ex) {
            entityManager.detach(existing);
             deleteEntityResponse.setErrorMessage("general.error.delete.DataIntegrityViolationException");
    }

        return new ResponseEntity<>(deleteEntityResponse,
                deleteEntityResponse.isDeleted()
                        ? HttpStatus.OK
                        : HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED);
    }
```

Later in the same Controller class I've defined Exception handling method:

```
 @ExceptionHandler
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleAllSortsOfExceptions(Exception exception) {
}
```

I'm expecting that when I try to delete an entity and operation fails with DataIntegrityViolationException I will get back `ResponseEntity<DeleteEntityResponse>`, but instead I'm getting back `ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse>`.

`ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse>` is returned through handleAllSortsOfExceptions() method. And that is being called with  org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly.

My question is - how to configure transaction management so that it understands the @Transactional annotations?

Comment: And why shouldn't a rollback occur? You cannot delete it so what do you think would happen. Also `@Transactional` on a controller is not something you generally do, you create a service, annotate that and handle the exception appropriately in your controller. Next to that you are catching the exception so it is never visible to the transaction management stuff. You are using Spring Boot so defining a `JpaTransactionManager` isn't needed. It also looks like you are reusing an instance variable `deleteEntityResponse` don't do that...

Comment: @M.Deinum , thanks for the feedback. I expect that if I handle the exception, the transaction can resume / commit.  For that I'm detaching the  entity from the entityManager (so that the changes aren't propagated further). I cannot re-throw the DataIntegrityException, cause the Exception will be picked up by exceptionHandler method. I agree, that I'm missing the service layer completely (as there is not much to do in the service layer). I'll fix the JpaTransactionManager. deleteEntityResponse is not an instance variable I simplified the example for SO

Comment: It will not, next to that it would break the A of ACID, it is either all or nothing but not almost everything but not this delete... Also why not simply create an `@ExceptionHandling` method for that specific exception? Simplifies your code imho. I still would suggest adding a service layer, currently you are doing everything in your web layer. The repository is also `@Transactional` and as soon as a `RuntimeException` occurs the transaction is marked for rollback, you are catching it and after wards it is trying to commit, hence your exception. You are imho making it to complex.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I even tried to add propagation = REQUIRES_NEW to the Transactional annotation in hope that it will start a new transaction for that specific delete method and that the main transaction will be able to commit. Furthermore, If it comes to all or nothing what's the use-case for Transactional.rollbackFor ?  I agree, that several ExceptionHandling methods could make the code look cleaner, but we have around 3-4 different type of Exceptions and handling just wraps the errorCodes into the JSON object. Method naming could be improved :)

Comment: It can be that you still want to commit if the error is recoverable, a `DataIntegrityViolationException` isn't recoverable. Using exceptions for control flow is a wrong approach (and is something that was done years ago). IMHO, move the code to a service method, catch the exceptions in controller and return the response you want. That way yu don't need to hack around. You are mainly trying to work around the fact you don't have a proper service layer and are trying to shoehorn everything in a single method. Also if you are using Spring boot you don't need `@EnableTransactionManagement`.

Comment: @M.Deinum, so what's a recoverable Exception in terms of jpa Transactions? Anything that's not related to DB layer? I'm not controlling the flow with Exceptions. The system is built around the principle that Controller is responsible for serving / manipulating one specific Resource. BaseController has the backbone for the CRUD operations and subclasses handle the difference in business logic. Introducing the service layer per specific DomainObject would definitely be an overkill here.

Comment: Ah the imho generic base class fallacy... We create one class, make it generic and expect it to work for everything... As mentioned before making your controller transactional is a very bad thing to do, imho. You are now basically making your transactions dependent on how your web layer behaves, not something you want. If you don't want a service layer, wrap the code in a `TransactionTemplate`, catch the exception and then return the response.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I would call that classic OOP, not a fallacy ;). Controllers are used as backend for angularJS enabled app. All presentation logic is handled on the client side. In this scenario controllers == service layer.  I guess that I simply do not see a use-case for noRollbackFor attribute. I've tried to configure it, something went wrong and that resulted in this question post

Comment: Your setup will simply never work, you are catching exceptions. Also the no rollback rule would in this case break the A from ACID. I don't agree that your controller is the service layer. The controller is the integration layer for calling your service layer. And I don't call that OOP I still see it as a fallacy (but that is my opinion). If you want to make it work, as stated wrap it in a `TransactionTemplate` the part that needs to be transactional.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I'll look into it. After your feedback it's visible that some parts of the code need to be refactored. Thanks for the help